# set hours and get ms with Date in js

Tags: javascript, date

how can I get the ms of the day at midnight with vanilla js ; something like this:

```
const today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)

return  today.getTime()
```

And as well how can i get the ms of just the current hours and minutes . Something like

```
const hours = new Date().gethours()
const minutes = new Date().getminutes()
const now = (hours + minutes) in millisecond
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> how can I get the ms of the day at midnight with vanilla js ; something like this:
>
> ```
> const today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)
> return  today.getTime()
> ```

You're close, but don't use the return value of `setHours`, use the date object:

```
const today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
return today.getTime();
```

That's working in local time. If you want UTC, use `setUTCHours` instead.

> And as well how can i get the ms of just the current hours and minutes . Something like
>
> const hours = new Date().gethours()
> const minutes = new Date().getminutes()
> const now = (hours + minutes) in millisecond

The methods are `getHours` and `getMinutes` (capitalization matters). If you're trying to get "milliseconds since midnight", it would be:

```
const dt = new Date();
const msSinceMidnight = ((dt.getHours() * 60) + dt.getMinutes()) * 60 * 1000;
return msSinceMidnight;
```

...since there are 60 minutes in an hour, 60 seconds in a minute, and 1000ms in a second. (Note that you haven't used `getSeconds` there, so seconds will be ignored.)

Comment: thank youuuuuuuuu!! the first case is exactly was I was looking for. The second question i solved like this but I'm wondering if there is a better way                                                            `const nowraw = new Date();
const hours = nowraw.getHours();
const minutes = nowraw.getMinutes();
const now = f_ms(0, hours) + f_ms(0, 0, minutes)`

Comment: @cri_pava - Sorry, I don't think I know what you're trying to do in that example (and of course, I don't know what `f_ms` is).

Comment: yes sorry . So basically I'm trying to compare the currently time with a time that stored in an object `const opening = 16  if (now > opening)  { Do something  }`

Answer (score 0):

[*setHours*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.sethours) returns the time value of the updated Date, so for the local midnight time value:

```
let today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

does the job. If you want local milliseconds since midnight, then:

```
let msSinceMidnight = new Date() - new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

Getting UTC milliseconds since midnight is simpler, as in ECMAScript UTC days are always 8.64e7 ms long:

```
let msSinceUTCMidnight = new Date() % 8.64e7;
```

```js
let today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(`today: ${today}`);

let msSinceMidnight = new Date() - new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);
console.log(`msSinceMidnight: ${msSinceMidnight}`);

let msSinceUTCMidnight = new Date() % 8.64e7;
console.log(`msSinceUTCMidnight: ${msSinceUTCMidnight}`);
```